# Why $|z-z_0|^2=r^2|z|^2\iff |z-\frac{z_0}{1-r^2}|=|\frac{rz_0}{1-r^2}|$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to prove that $$S=\left\{z\in\mathbb C\mid \left|\frac{z-z_0}{z}\right|=r\right\}$$
is a circle. In the correction it's written if $z\in S$, then $|z-z_0|^2=r^2|z|^2$ which is equivalent to $$\left|z-\frac{z_0}{1-r^2}\right|=\left|\frac{rz_0}{1-r^2}\right|.$$

I don't see how we get $\left|z-\frac{z_0}{1-r^2}\right|=\left|\frac{rz_0}{1-r^2}\right|$ from $|z-z_0|^2=r^2|z|^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|z-z_0|^2=r^2|z|^2$$
$$|z|^2-\bar{z}z_0-z\bar{z_0}+|z_0|^2=r^2|z|^2$$
$$(1-r^2)|z|^2-\bar{z}z_0-z\bar{z_0}+|z_0|^2=0$$
$$|z|^2-\bar{z}\Big(\dfrac{z_0}{1-r^2}\Big)-z\Big(\overline{\dfrac{z_0}{1-r^2}}\Big)+\Big|\dfrac{z_0}{1-r^2}\Big|^2=\Big|\dfrac{z_0}{1-r^2}\Big|^2-\dfrac{|z_0|^2}{1-r^2}$$
$$\Big|z-\frac{z_0}{1-r^2}\Big|^2=\Big|\dfrac{rz_0}{1-r^2}\Big|^2$$

Answer (score 1):

We may assume $z_0\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\left\|z-z_0\right\|=r\|z\|$ implies:
$$ (z-z_0)(\bar{z}-z_0) = r^2 z\bar{z} \tag{1}$$
and the resulting equation (provided that $r\neq 1$) is trivially the equation of a circle.